# Cucumber-like testing for my API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

I have been writing my Rails application with Cucumber in TDD mode: Tests first, then the code. Now my application needs an API. What I like about cucumber is, that I can specify my tests in plain English, so even managers understand what's going on.

Is there any way I can do this for my JSON-API?

Comment: There's a way to do **anything**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely achieve this. You can write step definitions to assert/verify your json responses. Something like this

```
Given a username and password
When I try to login via the API 
Then I should get logged in
```

While this works, this just tests the API ( controllers/actions ) work or not, ie more like "functional" testing, not Acceptance testing. As such you are not going to test the API consumer itself.

Answer (score 2):

YES! This is totally possible.  Have you checked out the Cucumber Book by the Pragmatic Programmer series?

Here's a quick example:

```
Feature: Addresses
  In order to complete the information on the place
  I need an address

Scenario: Addresses
  Given the system knows about the following addresses:
   [INSERT TABLE HERE or GRAB FROM DATABASE]
  When client requests GET /addresses
  Then the response should be JSON:
  """
    [
     {"venue": "foo", "address": "bar"},
     { more stuff }
    ]
  """
```

STEP DEFINITION:

```
Given(/^the system knows about the following addresses:$/) do |addresses| 
# table is a Cucumber::Ast::Table
  File.open('addresses.json', 'w') do |io|
    io.write(addresses.hashes.to_json)
  end
end    

When(/^client requests GET (.*)$/) do |path|
   @last_response = HTTParty.get('local host url goes here' + path)
end

Then /^the response should be JSON:$/ do |json|
   JSON.parse(@last_response.body).should == JSON.parse(json)
end
```

ENV File:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', '..', 'address_app')
require 'rack/test'
require 'json'
require 'sinatra'
require 'cucumber'
require 'httparty'
require 'childprocess'
require 'timeout'

server = ChildProcess.build("rackup", "--port", "9000")
server.start
Timeout.timeout(3) do
  loop do
    begin
      HTTParty.get('local host here')
      break
    rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED => try_again
      sleep 0.1
    end
  end
end

at_exit do
  server.stop
end
```